# How to link back to specific jquery-ui tabs during the pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I'm new to PHP and jquery-ui,

I have a problems in my php projects, I'm doing pagination within a jquery-ui tabs, but when click on next page or page number the page refreshed and display the 1st tab, while the pagination table is in 2nd tab. The following is my pagination code.

```
 <?php

       $range = 3;
       if ($currentpage > 1) {
          echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
          $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
          echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
       } 

       for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
           if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
                if ($x == $currentpage) {
                    echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
                } else {
                echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
                } 
            } 
       }       

       if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
          $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
          echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
          echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
        }
  ?>
```

I had tried to replace `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with #usersTab2 (the tab I wanted to go) but it wont work.
I'm using php $_GET method to get the current page data.The pagination works well, just I can't link back to the specific tab I want...

Hope to get replay and your help is much appreciate~ =)
ps: I'm sry for my english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to all tabs;

And when load this page, create a rule to get value in hash from url and fire a click event in js.

Example:

```
url = test.com/#tab2
```

When page is ready, get the value in hash and fire event:

```
var div = get the value in hash url;
$("#"+div).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript to target and load your pages. By using HTML links, the browser will refresh the page. I would suggest using the jQuery `load()` function.

Example:
`<a href='javascript:void()' class='nextpage'>&raquo;</a>`

Then in your script:
`$('.nextpage').click(function() { $('#page').load('loader.php?page=number'); });`

Comment: My number is in php format, I cant directly apply it to javascript rite?

Comment: No, but you could have PHP generate parts of your JS.